# How to output a hyphen after each character with restrictions using nested for loops in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I just have one small issue with outputting a hyphen after every character (including the three dots shown in the code below)

Sample input

```
  2 (option #)
  disappear (phrase)
```

Expected output:

```
 d-i-s-a-p-p-e-a-r-.-.-.
 d-i-s-a-p-p-e-a-.-.-.
 d-i-s-a-p-p-e-.-.-.
 d-i-s-a-p-p-.-.-.
 d-i-s-a-p-.-.-.
 d-i-s-a-.-.-.
 d-i-s-.-.-.
 d-i-.-.-.
 d-.-.-.
 .-.-.
 .-.
 .
```

**It outputs the "-" after every character excluding the last dot**

I got the "-" to display after very word character but cant figure out displaying after the dots too, like it works but there has to be one less hypen:

My actual output:

```
d-i-s-a-p-p-e-a-r-.-.-.-
 d-i-s-a-p-p-e-a-.-.-.-
 d-i-s-a-p-p-e-.-.-.-
 d-i-s-a-p-p-.-.-.-
 d-i-s-a-p-.-.-.-
 d-i-s-a-.-.-.-
 d-i-s-.-.-.-
 d-i-.-.-.-
 d-.-.-.-
 .-.-.-
 .-.-
 .-
```

**I am partially done, I just need one less hyphen which would automatically also fulfill the requirement of not displaying a hyphen after the very last dot.**

Code:

```
       else if (option == 2){
             for (int x = 0; x < phrase.length(); x++){
                for (int y = 0; y < phrase.length() - x; y++){
                    char n = phrase.charAt(y);
                    System.out.print(n+"-");
                }
                for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++){
                    System.out.print("."+"-");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                for (int i = 0; i < 3 - j; i++){
                    System.out.print("."+"-");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you need to use loops? Otherwise getting the char array and then joining it would be a lot simpler and less code to write

Comment: Yes only using for loops, and no arrays, or any built-in methods of java

Comment: @HussainOmer "any" built-in method would include `System.out.println`, `String.charAt`, `String.length` etc though, all of which you have used. I guess a better way of saying it is "methods I didn't use in my code are not allowed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could remove the last `-` is to only print `-` when it's *not the last iteration*. You can check that it's not the last iteration by checking `loopVariable != loopBound - 1`.

So your code would be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < phrase.length(); x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < phrase.length() - x; y++){
        char n = phrase.charAt(y);
        System.out.print(n+"-");
    }

    // You could just print the literal "--.-." instead
    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++){
        System.out.print(".");
        if (a != 2) { // Notice here!
            System.out.print("-");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 - j; i++){
        System.out.print(".");
        if (i != 2 - j) { // and here
            System.out.print("-");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here's how I would do it:

```
// pretend that the phrase is 3 characters longer than it actually is...
// because of the three dots at the end
for (int x = 0; x < phrase.length() + 3; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < phrase.length() + 3 - x; y++){
        char n;
        // Should we print the phrase or the dots?
        if (y < phrase.length() - x) {
            n = phrase.charAt(y);
        } else {
            n = '.';
        }
        System.out.print(n);
        if (y != phrase.length() + 2 - x) { // same trick of checking if it is last iteration
            System.out.print("-");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Is there not a way to reduce the hyphen? All i want to do is remove one hyphen

Comment: @HussainOmer I mean, you could print a `\b` character to delete the last character you printed, but I feel that kind of goes against the spirit of this (maybe homework?) exercise...

Comment: Yes it does, Ok so I tried ur method, I will edit my code with the current updated code I have and show you my actual output

Comment: @HussainOmer I just realised a mistake. See thee edit.

Comment: Ok thanks, it works now, but can you explain to me the logic behind != 2?

Comment: `2` is the loop bound, 3, minus 1. `2 - j` is the loop bound, `3 - j`, minus 1. Notice that `3 - j - 1 == 2 - j`. @HussainOmer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214843/discussion-between-sweeper-and-hussain-omer).

Comment: Yes sorry I just figured that out because if (a != 2) is the same as saying if (a < 3 - 1)